# Not able to decode traditional chinese using java

Tags: java, decode

I want to display a string  which is in traditional Chinese language into my application GUI.
While debugging eclipse showed this string  as some mixture of English alphabets and square boxes.
This is the java code which I used to decode it. The string 'str' I am getting from a traditional Chinese .mpg stream.

```
String TRADITIONAL_CHINESE_ENC = "Big5";
byte[] tmp = str.getBytes();
String decodedString=new String(tmp,TRADITIONAL_CHINESE_ENC);
```

But  the result i am getting in decodedString is also a mixture of alphabets,square boxes,and some question mark embedded in a diamond shaped box etc.
This is happening only in case of traditional Chinese language. The same code works fine for simplified chinese,korean languages etc.

What could be wrong in my code when dealing with traditional Chinese?
I am using UTF-8 encoding  for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with that code.

According to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding), there are 3 common encodings for traditional Chinese characters: [Guobiao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guobiao_code), UTF-8 and Big5.  I suggest you try the two alternatives that you haven't tried, and if that fails try some of the less common alternatives listed.

(It is also possible that the real problem is in the way you are displaying the String ... but the fact that you are displaying Simplified Chinese and Korean correctly suggests that this is not the problem.)

---

> I am using UTF-8 encoding for eclipse.

I don't think that is relevant.  The code you showed us doesn't depend on the default character encoding of either the execution platform or the IDE.